# 400% difference in CPU usage between "Task Manager" and "Sysinternal's Process Explorer"

Tags: windows, cpu-usage

On one specific server I have 400% difference in CPU usage between "Task Manager" and "Sysinternal's Process Explorer" (both picture taken on the same screenshot, so at the exact same time).
What can be the cause of this discrepancy?
 
edit: Process Explorer is ran with elevated privilege. But no difference if ran as regular user (except we do not see each process details).
 
 
 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you running as Administrator? See File menu. Might make a difference if it can't see all the processes?

Comment: This is probably a better fit for SuperUser or SysInternals forums. If you want to really compare it would require perfmon data. My guess would be ProcExp is not including it's usage...

Comment: Not answering your question... Most of CPU usage is in kernel time. I would suspect a driver that is using/abusing the CPU.